# Gurobi in python to calculate lp norm

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

Gurobi in python to calculate l1 norm

I am trying to calculate l1 norm by using Gurobi in python. Since I am new to python and Gurobi, I am here to ask for help.

The model is:

```
minimize 1^T(r+ + r-)
s.t. y - X beta = r+ - r-
r+ >= 0 and r- >= 0
```

Where y is a n vector and X is a n-by-p matrix. r+, r- is n vector and beta is a p vector
Here is my code, I don`t know what is wrong, is anyone could help me out?

---

```
row col = X.shape

# import Gurobi
from gurobipy import *

# model
m = Model("l1-norm")

# create decision variables
r_plus = []
for i in range(row):
    r_plus = m.addVar(name="r_plus%d" % i)
r_minus = []
for i in range(row):
    r_minus = m.addVar(name = "r_minu%d" % i)
beta = []
for j in range(col):
    beta = m.addVar(name = "beta%d" % j)

# Update model to integrate new variables
m.update()

# set objective
m.setObjective(sum(r_plus) + sum(r_minus), GRB.MINIMIZE)

# add model constraint
for i in range(row):
m.addConstr(y[i] - quicksum(X[[i], j] * beta[j] for j in range(col)) == r_plus[i] - r_minus[i])

# solve
m.optimize()
```

Comment: Please post the error message you get

Comment: Thanks for asking, the error message I got currently is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6cba6fe781b1> in <module>()
     21 
     22 # set objective
---> 23 m.setObjective(sum(r_plus) + sum(r_minus), GRB.MINIMIZE)
     24 
     25 # add model constraint

TypeError: 'Var' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your arrays of variables wrong, it should be

```
r_plus = []
for i in range(row):
    r_plus.append(m.addVar(name="r_plus%d" % i))
r_minus = []
for i in range(row):
    r_minus.append(m.addVar(name = "r_minu%d" % i))
beta = []
for j in range(col):
    beta.append(m.addVar(name = "beta%d" % j))
```

or more briefly

```
r_plus  = [m.addVar(name="r_plus%d" % i) for i in range(row)]
r_minus = [m.addVar(name="r_minu%d" % i) for i in range(row)]
beta = [m.addVar(name = "beta%d" % j) for j in range(col)]
```